# I can't get google maps API to work with my simple web page?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I followed the w3schools javascript tutorial exactly, but I can not get these google maps to load on my simple web page.  Help please! Pretty new to javascript.  I'm just typing more here to increase my english:code ratio for stackoverflow.

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
  
  <script>
  function initialize(){
    var mapProp1 = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(69.336822, -44.218045),
    zoom:9,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var mapProp2 = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.336822, -84.218045),
    zoom:9,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map1"),mapProp1);
  var map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map2"),mapProp2);

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
  
  </script>

  </head>

  
   <body>

    

       
      <div class="content-inner">
        <div id="map1"></div>
        <div id="map2"></div>

      </div>
    
    
  

     




     <footer>
    
     </footer>



    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you are missing a closing brace on your initialize function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have three issues:

1. you need to close your initialize function
2. You are missing a semicolon at the end of mapProp2
3. You need to set the size of the map

the following should get you started:

```
function initialize(){    
var mapProp1 = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.336822, -84.218045),
    zoom:9,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var mapProp2 = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.336822, -84.218045),
    zoom:9,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
  }; // <-- the semicolon was missing
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map1"),mapProp1);
  var map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map2"),mapProp2);
} //<-- this closing brace was missing

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);



 <div class="content-inner">
    <!-- in production you should not use inline style. do this in css -->
    <div id="map1" style="height:300px;width:300px;"></div>
    <div id="map2" style="height:300px;width:300px;"></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't running your site on localhost you might be running into security issues.  I would look into running `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` in the root of your project.  It should launch an instance of localhost:8000 allowing you to develop your site without running into any security issues.  There are obviously many methods to accomplish this but this is simple enough to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
  <script>
  function initialize(){
    var mapProp1 = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.336822, -84.218045),
    zoom:9,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var mapProp2 = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.336822, -84.218045),
    zoom:9,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map1"),mapProp1);
  var map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map2"),mapProp2);
  }
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
  </script>
  </head>
   <body>
      <div class="content-inner">
        <div id="map1" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>
        <div id="map2" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>
      </div>
     <footer></footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is an example in [JsBin](http://jsbin.com/tovogocowi/1/edit)